# Angular $watch strange behavior

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have the following $watch:

```
$scope.$watch('someParentClass.someClass.index', (newIndexValue: number) => {
                if (_.isNumber(newIndexValue)) {
                    //Do something
                }
            }, true);
```

Which I want to trigger following these lines:

Lines 1, 2 and 3:

```
public foo(): someClass{

    let obj: someClass;



    obj = {
        id?: number,
        index: number,
    };

    obj.activeSectionIndex = 0; // Line 1
    obj.activeSectionIndex = 1; // Line 2
    obj.activeSectionIndex = 2; // Line 3

    //...

    return obj;
}
```

Line 4:

```
public update(exploration: someClass): void {

    //...

    let index = 5;

    exploration.index = index; // Line 4

    //...
}
```

The problem is that the watch is triggered only after `return obj;` in the first case with the value `obj.activeSectionIndex = 2` (The updates of the value to 0 and 1 are ignored), and isn't triggered at all in the second case of line 4.

**Previous answers to similar questions** suggested the following solutions:

- Not to copy the value, but create a reference. (Tried that by creating a new object and updating exploration to reference it.)
- Tried changing the callback to get newVal and oldVal instead of just newVal.
- Tried setting the objectEquality flag to true. And tried removing it altogether.
- Tried changing $watch to $scope.$watchCollection.

None of these solutions worked.
Any suggestions on how to tackle this issue? Thanks.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).